# linux/solaris + manipulation of Standard Output

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, solaris, logs

I run the following line on linux/solaris machine ( all output will write in to /tmp/Log from application.bin )

```
 ./application.bin 1>>/tmp/Log
```

We can see the content of the /tmp/Log file

```
 more /tmp/Log

/etc/opt/OA/share/conf/OpC/mgmt_sv/ui/registration/C/opc_op /etc/opt/OA/share/conf/analysis/system_odbc.iniaaaa
/etc/opt/OA/share/conf/ovspmd.authaaaa
/etc/opt/OA/share/conf/ovwdb.authaaaa
/etc/opt/OA/share/conf/ovw.authaaaa
```

My question:

what I need to change or add in the syntax:

```
   "1>>/tmp/Log" ?
```

in order to add space between each line as the following example

```
       /etc/opt/OA/share/conf/OpC/mgmt_sv/ui/registration/C/opc_op
  .
       /etc/opt/OA/share/conf/analysis/system_odbc.iniaaaa
  .
       /etc/opt/OA/share/conf/ovspmd.authaaaa
  .
       /etc/opt/OA/share/conf/ovwdb.authaaaa
  .
       /etc/opt/OA/share/conf/ovw.authaaaa
```

Remark – the option to add space between each line after /tmp/Log was created isn’t relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./application.bin | sed '$!G' >> /tmp/Log
```

Comment: `$` meaning "only on the last line"; `!` negate the line selector, i.e. on every line except the last one; `G` append a new-line to pattern (the line) and the "hold space" (empty by default) - equivalent of `s/$/\n/`